# Tree graph in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, graph, tree

How to get this:

```
<ul>
  <input type="text" placeholder="A" />
  <ul>
    <input type="text" placeholder="B" />
    <ul>
      <input type="text" placeholder="D" />
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <input type="text" placeholder="E" />
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <input type="text" placeholder="C" />
    <ul>
      <input type="text" placeholder="F" />
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <input type="text" placeholder="G" />
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

out of it:

```
const graph = {
  A: ['B', 'C'],
  B: ['D', 'E'],
  C: ['F', 'G'],
  D: [],
  E: [],
  F: [],
  G: [],
 }
```

const graph means:

```
        A
      /   \
     B     C
    / \   / \
   D   E F   G
```

Without using oop graph.
You can remove input from lists, then just insert the name of the vertex.

Comment: The expected markup is invalid

Comment: I tried to use recursion but with no success. 
Perhaps I am setting the graph incorrectly, and the only solution is through OOP, but I would like to solve it as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to draw dom via binary tree algorithm i.e. depth first.

Algorithm is:

1. Draw root element, find its children
2. Start from first child, draw it, find its children
3. Keep on repeating step 2 until you you reach bottom of the tree.
4. Then go to next child from step 2 and perform same steps as for the first child.

By following above steps I think you can easily draw DOM using depth first binary tree algorithm.

Take a look at sample below

```
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
const graph = {
  A: ['B', 'C'],
  B: ['D', 'E'],
  C: ['F', 'G'],
  D: [],
  E: [],
  F: [],
  G: [],
  
 }
 
 const root = document.getElementById("root"); 
 
 const findchildren = (node) => graph[node]
 
 const drawNode = (node) => {
    const input = document.createElement("input"); 
  input.setAttribute("type", "text");
  input.setAttribute("placeholder", node);
  root.appendChild(input); 
  const children = findchildren(node)
  if (children.length > 0) {
    children.forEach(item => drawNode(item))    
  }
 }
 
 drawNode("A")
```

Comment: Yes, i think this is post order graph traversal. This works when I use the class node with data, left and right fields.

Comment: let me write sample code for you. gimme a moment.

Comment: do u would can check my solution?

Comment: looks great. I tried making compact version.

Answer (score 1):

I do this, but not enjoy.
A draft, maybe I'll improve it, but I've been doing it all day, so I'm tired.

```
 const dataset = {
   A: ['B', 'C'],
   B: ['D', 'E'],
   C: ['F', 'G'],
   D: [],
   E: [],
   F: [],
   G: [],
 }
const $tree = document.querySelector('.tree')
function graphToHTML(node, root) {
  if (Object.values(node)[0].length === 0) return
  let ul = document.createElement('ul')
  let input = document.createElement('input')
  input.placeholder = Object.values(node)[0][0]
  root.append(ul)
  ul.append(input)
  graphToHTML(
    { [Object.values(node)[0][0]]: dataset[Object.values(node)[0][0]] },
    ul
  )
  ul = document.createElement('ul')
  input = document.createElement('input')
  input.placeholder = Object.values(node)[0][1]
  root.append(ul)
  ul.append(input)
  graphToHTML(
    { [Object.values(node)[0][1]]: dataset[Object.values(node)[0][1]] },
    ul
  )
}

let ul = document.createElement('ul')
let input = document.createElement('input')
input.placeholder = Object.keys(dataset)[0]

ul.append(input)
$tree.append(ul)
graphToHTML({ A: ['B', 'C'] }, ul)
```